# Start service as an other user in debian

Tags: debian, privileges

I have a debian system where I installed the unifi controler as a root. Now I have a new user in the sudo group and I want to run the services without root privileges.

I don't want to remove and install the service because I was tricky the last time to reconnect the switches and aps.

Is there any simple method to change the user of the installion?